# Angular Material Datepicker getConnectedOverlayOrigin method

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I was going through the Angular Material Datepicker API documentation and came across
getConnectedOverlayOrigin method, dose anyone know or have an example on how to use this method. I was not able to find any examples and documentation dose not have much implementation details.

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

[image]

Comment: Basically it gets element based on which overlay's positioning is calculated. It's related to CDK overlay's `ConnectedPositionStrategy`. Reading up all the docs on the [CDK overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview), and especially on the [position strategies](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#position-strategies) should give you some more insight.